# Calculating height of a div using Less.js in a liquid layout

Tags: jquery, css, height, less, liquid-layout

I have a liquid layout and am learning/ using Less.js for my CSS.

I have a div 'A' that needs to take account of the user viewbox, substract another div 'B' height (which is in %) and finally another div 'C' which is in pixel.

Here is what I thought would work but doesn't:

```
@menubarsHeight: 7%;   // declaring variable with div 'B' 's height.
@ttlHeight: '$(window).height()';     // calculating height using jquery 
@midParentHeight: -20px + @didParentHeight - @menubarsHeight;     // calculating the height based on the above two variables, -20px is the height of div 'C'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things unclear here. Namely, you don't tell us what `@didParentHeight` is, and you calculate `@ttlHeight` but don't use it. Nor do you state explicitly what div B's parent is (the window?).

Given these uncertainties, I will assume some things and attempt an answer. If all three div's have the window as their parent, and your javascript is giving a correct window height, then it seems like this would be the answer:

```
@menubarsHeight: 0.07; /* define as decimal */
@midParentHeight: @ttlHeight - 20px - (@ttlHeight * @menubarsHeight);
```

I use `0.07` instead of `7%` because I'm not quite sure if LESS will do the multiplication correctly using a percentage (it would be mixing `px` and `%` units). So with the decimal, then assuming `@ttlHeight` were `100px`, this should calculate to:

```
@midParentHeight: 100px - 20px - (100px * 0.07);
```

Which should become:

```
@midParentHeight: 100px - 20px - 7px = 73px
```

If you need to use the `@menubarsHeight` to later actually define your div B, then do this (which will take the decimal and put it into a `%` unit value for css):

```
div.B { height: percentage(@menubarsHeight); }
```

Comment: Thank you ScottS. I was playing around with the variables and incorrectly inserted the old ref. to another variable. Your answer is correct, except now I am getting 'C operate is not a function' error when I load the page. I suspect its to do with the jquery in less.js. Is there any ref. for how to link jquery in less?

Comment: P.S: I will check this as correct answer tomorrow. Am hoping to get the jquery issue resolved hence leaving this open till tomorrow. Best,

Comment: @Kayote--maybe [this site](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2010/03/css-less-jquery-plugin.html) will help with your jquery. I don't really have much experience with LESS, and no experience integrating it with jquery.

Comment: Thanks ScottS, it appears to be a separate plugin for incorporating jquery functionality in less... Im looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, as it turns out, you donot need less/ js to do what I was trying to do i.e. calculate the height of viewport.

The following simple CSS resolved the issue. However, ScottS's answer is awesome for Less query.

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 1.5%;
    right: 1.5%;
```